# What kind of specific projects can I do to master bitwise operations in C++? Also is there a canonical book?

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I don't use C++ or bitwise operations at my current job but I'm thinking of applying to companies where it is a requirement to be fluent with them (on their tests anyway).

**So my question is:** Can anyone suggest a project which will require gaining a fluency in bitwise operations to complete?

On a side note, is there a canonical book on optimization techniques using bitwise operations since that seems to be an important use of them?

Comment: (1) Understand all the two operand [truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) (and how to construct each of them out of just 'and', 'or', and 'not' combinations), (2) be able to count in [gray code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) if necessary, (3) optimize the logic with a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no mystery to bitwise operations. Perhaps you're thinking of some of the crazy bit twiddling tricks that people have come up with over the years? For example, Stanford has a page with [a long list of such tricks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html). Your best bet there is to just start with a list such as the one I linked and go through a number of them. Step through them in a debugger if it helps. Once you understand a handful of them, you'll get more comfortable thinking in those terms.

Comment: Thanks! That is exactly the kind of information I was looking for, I just didn't know the precise terminology.

Answer (score 2):

You'd hardly need a book to figure this out, only to know how numbers are represented in binary. Buy yourself a pad and pencil and draw some [Truth Tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)

As for a project, how about writing an algorithm that takes an image bitmap and draws/blits it transparently onto another image using masks. Allow the user to select the transparent colour.

Comment: Do truth tables help you figure out the practical applications of bitwise operations or optimization techniques in C++?

Comment: Practical yes, language agnostic, what optimisation techniques are you referring to?